# Not able to take a console on browser for HP StorageWorks 4/16 SAN Switch

Tags: switch-statement, san

I have HP StorageWorks 4/16 SAN Switch and not able to take a console form any browser,
When I try to login on to the browser getting the error "The Version of Java Plugin needed to run the application is not installed. The Page from where the plugin can be downloaded will be opened into the new window"

Also, I have saw that it is continuously reloading that page also,
Kindly help me with this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try using old Java, version 6, I guess, and Firefox.